# How does namespace works inside of laravel route group

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

Routes defines like this in Laravel, I would like to know how Route::get referring to the parent class/namespace.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'site'], function()
{
 Route::get('/home', function(){});
}
```

I mean how does Rout::get cloud get parameters has been set in Route::group

Answer (score 0):

namespace is your folder name  in which you have created your file

example :

inside `app/Http/Controllers/` , you have create folder `site` and there you put one file called `MyController.php`

so you can add `namespace="site"` route group to all routes , for which all the controllers are inside `site` folder.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'site'], function()
{
 Route::get('/home','MyController@home');
 Route::get('/test','MySecondController@test');
}
```

inside you MyController.php , you will use this line :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\site;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function home(Request $request){
        return view('home');
    }   
}
```

same in your MySecondController.php you have to add :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\site;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I meant something else. I just edited my question.

Comment: @Arian , what to you want to get inside your `Route::get()` from your `Route::group()` ?

Comment: Route::group got it's own parameters so how to access that parameters from Route::get?

Comment: @Arian , please describe what parameters you want to get ?

Comment: Note that this is a sample I want to now how to work with Namespaces and scope. And how to change scope of function to its parent.

Comment: @Arian it is unclear what you want to accomplish here - `Route::group` does not receive or provide any parameters. You also haven't set any route parameters in your route. Do you need to access input (like GET or POST parameters)? Use `Input::get('key', 'default_value')`.